# Switch poles from inverted power to make negative positive?

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, inverter

My understanding is that voltage is relative (where you measure affects voltage) and that current flows with voltage difference.

Why can't you just switch the poles/wires of an inverted signal/power supply to get a non-inverted output?

This is mostly in reference to power supplies (switching/voltage regulators) and op-amps, but sort of curious as to theory as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output of a power supply is *isolated*, meaning it can float over a range of voltage relative to its input, then the polarity of its output is only relative.  Whether it is a positive or negative supply is only determined by how you think of it and how you hook it up to your load relative to whatever it is you consider 0 V.

If a power supply is not isolated, then it is already referenced to some other voltage.  If your load is also connected back to that node somehow, then you can't just flip the leads of the DC output around.  For example, you might have a 5 V power supply that runs off of the battery in your car.  If it is not isolated, the negative output of that supply will most likely be connected to the negative output of the battery, which is connected to the chassis of your car.  If you are powering something that also connects to the chassis, then you can't flip the leads around and think of it as a -5 V supply.

On the other hand, if you have a power supply that plugs into the wall, most likely its outputs are isolated from the wall power and therefore the wall plug ground.  In that case you can flip the leads around any way you wish to consider it a positive or negative supply.

Answer (score 4):

That is fine so long as the signal/power is isolated from the common reference/ground. In fact, using an *isolated* DC-DC regulator, it is common to swap the output leads to get negative voltage.

The problem is that generally, one side of everything is connected to a common reference/ground. For example, on an ATX power supply, the negative side of +12V, +5V, +3.3V are all connected together on the black wires. If you try to reverse the +5V rail, for example, you will end up shorting out that rail.

If you have a signal or power source that does not reference the common ground, you can easily invert it as you suggest. The problem is that it is often harder or more expansive to have these isolated.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat negative as ground and therefore your positive is positive with respect to ground (obvious!). Or you can tie positive to ground and your negative rail becomes a negative supply. It doesn't really matter at the end of the day but when it comes to signals (such as audio for instance), they like to be referenced to real ground so having a negative power supply voltage makes things a little tricker because most audio amps like to see a positive supply with respect to ground and ground is assumed to be the most negative rail in a power supply.

Same with a lot of power supply chips - most smpsu chips are positive supply devices (with respect to ground) but with a little bit of ingenuity can be made to work with a negative supply voltage.